# Unhandled Exception: The getter 'name' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hooolaaa Community, Here i am have a very interesting problem that i don't really understand,
I defined a String variable (String uName = "";) and i passed my current user name to it by doing (   uName =  userCurrentInfo.name; ), after that I use in 2 Text Widget(Text('${userCurrentInfo?.name}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Brand Bold"),),
The Issue :
It doesn't display the user name sometimes, until i restart my android studio and uninstall my app and do a fresh restart, then it start working. while some other time it just works.
What i Have Tried:
I have tried calling directly from the currentUser name from firebase like this: ( Text('${userCurrentInfo?.name}',) and this work, But i dont want to have to repeat this every-time i want to use the name of my current User.
Thanks for your time

Here is the Error Message:
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  static const String idScreen = "mainScreen";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin
{
   String uName="";

     void locatePosition() async
  {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
     LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    String address = await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position, context);
    print("This is your Address :: " + address);

    initGeoFireListner();

 =====>     uName =  userCurrentInfo.name; // I have user name stored in my uName String Variable.

     appFirebaseMonitoring();

    AssistantMethods.retrieveHistoryInfo(context);
  }

// I used it my Drawer in the build method 

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createIconMarker();
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 255.0,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              //Drawer Header
              Container(
                height: 165.0,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/user_icon.png", height: 65.0, width: 65.0,),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0,),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(uName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Brand Bold"),),
                            SizedBox(height: 6.0,),
                            GestureDetector(
                                onTap: ()
                                {
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ProfileTabPage()));
                                },
                                child: Text("Visit Profile")
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter you need to update the state of a widget manually. what that means is that if you have a variable like `var name = "temp"` and you build a widget like `Text(name)` it's going to display `temp`. Then if you change the `name` variable to `myName`, the text will still display `temp`, that's because you need to redraw your layout to be built with the new value.

In the `State` of a `StatefulWidget`, you have states(variables), and when they change, you need to call `setState`. `setState` will redraw your layout with the new state(variable):

```dart
void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
     LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    String address = await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position, context);
    print("This is your Address :: " + address);

    initGeoFireListner();

    setState((){ // rebuild this widget with this changes
      uName =  userCurrentInfo.name;
    });

    appFirebaseMonitoring();

    AssistantMethods.retrieveHistoryInfo(context);
  }
```

I also didn't see where do you call `locatePosition`?

The simplest way to call it would be in `initState` inside `_MainScreenState`:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    locatePosition();
  }
```

---

If `userCurrentInfo?.name` works then there is 2 things you can do:

1. Make `uName` a global getter:

```dart
import '...';

String get uName => userCurrentInfo?.name ?? '';

class ... {
 ...
}
```

2. Initialize `uName` to `userCurrentInfo?.name`:

```dart
  String uName = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    uName =  userCurrentInfo?.name ?? '';
  }
```

Comment: Okay I tried doing this:  setState((){ // rebuild this widget with this changes
      uName =  userCurrentInfo.name;
    }); it didn't work

Comment: And Also the initState None Work

Comment: My code share the whole mainscreen code, Its just that its 1300 lines of code

Comment: There is lots of stuff missing. like, whatever `createIconMarker` does, you shouldn't call it inside `build`. and where does `userCurrentInfo` come from? is it a static global variable? if that's the case, you can just use a top-level getter to get the user's name and remove `uName` altogether.

Comment: Hello Mr Aligator, Is there a away i can send you the script. Cause i dont why its miss behaving  but when i use userCurrentInfo?.name it works. Just want to understand what i am doing wrong and why when i run the app it gets the name from firebase and some other times it doesn't work (when i define the uName variable)

Comment: I think that Your mistake is that you never assign the value of `userCurrentInfo?.name` to `uName` before the widget is rendered. I edited my answer. Try one of the new solutions.